# Orika: map constant default value to a field

Tags: java, mapping, orika

Is there a way using [Orika](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/index.html) to set the value of a field to a literal or constant value?

I mean something like:

```
public class ObjectMapper extends ConfigurableMapper {

        protected void configure(MapperFactory factory) {
             factory.classMap(SourceClass.class, DestinationClass.class)
             .field("myField", "CONSTANT_VALUE")
             .byDefault()
             .register();
        }
}
```

I can't find something similar in documentation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this section](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/advanced-mappings.html) of Orika docs, the only way to set a literal value is by customizing mapping. For example:

```
public class ObjectMapper extends ConfigurableMapper {

        protected void configure(MapperFactory factory) {
             factory.classMap(SourceClass.class, DestinationClass.class)
             .byDefault()
             .customize(new CustomMapper<SourceClass, DestinationClass>() {
                @Override
                public void mapAtoB(SourceClass a, DestinationClass b, MappingContext context) {
                    b.setMyField("CONSTANT_VALUE");
                }

                // ...
            })
            .register();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple solution

```
public class ObjectMapper extends ConfigurableMapper {

    protected void configure(MapperFactory factory) {
         factory.classMap(SourceClass.class, DestinationClass.class)
         .field("", "myField:{|setMyField('MY CONSTANT')}")
         .byDefault()
         .register();
    }
}
```

the source can be empty, you just need to fill the destination, with the name of the property and the setter method.